# Force image to bottom of column when using grid with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using a grid with two columns for a chat input box similar to Apple's iphone. The left column has a div for text and grows upward as text expands. However I would like the image in the right hand column to stay anchored to the bottom as shown in picture below but currently, it is anchored (and rises) to the top as you add text and the box expands.

[image]

Evidently I can't use position for the image as that does not play well with grid. (Position removes the item from the grid.) I really like Grid cause it has solved the problem of keeping the image to the right, but have this one remaining issue.

How can I keep the image at the bottom of the grid column?

CSS:

```
.inputContainer {
border-radius: 20px;
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: solid 2px #EEE;
  display: inline-block; 
position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
display: grid; grid-template-columns: 260px 40px;//USING GRID HERE
}
.inputBoxInner {
border-radius: 20px;
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 240px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
height:" auto";
display: inline-block; 
}
```

html:

```
<div class = "inputContainer" contentEditable="true"><div class="inputBoxInner" id="newmessage" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Start typing"></div><img src="/images/up-arrow-blue-75.png" width="30" height="30  style="float:right;" onclick="sendMessage();"></div></div>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want the image to stay at the BOTTOM as the text expands upward.  See edited image above with arrow showing desired position at bottom of grid column, not top.

Comment: can you upload image button link? so it's easy to align

Comment: don't understand what you mean. The image is just a png of an arrow. onClick fires some javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `align-self` and `justify-self` rules on your `<img>` element.

Here, I've removed the inline `float: right` and set the "icon" `class` on this image. Then I'm using this class to target it in CSS and set its position to bottom-right with value "end" for both those rules.

```css
.inputContainer {
  border-radius: 20px;
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: solid 2px #EEE;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 260px 40px; //USING GRID HERE
}

.inputBoxInner {
  border-radius: 20px;
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 240px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: " auto";
  display: inline-block;
}

.inputContainer .icon {
  align-self: end;
  justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputContainer" contentEditable="true">

  <div class="inputBoxInner" id="newmessage" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Start typing">
    sample long text sample long text sample long text sample long text sample long text sample long text sample long text sample long text sample long text sample long text
  </div>
  <img class="icon" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pics.freeicons.io/uploads/icons/png/4953436661577436996-512.png" width="30" height="30" onclick="sendMessage();">
  
</div>
```

Comment: I am marking this correct as there is no question your snippet accomplishes the goal. However, my code is still not working and I can't figure out why. Can you explain the notation: .inputContainer .icon   Is this any different from just .icon?

Comment: .input Container .icon is more specific, it CSS all rules have their own specify strength.

`.icon { ... } // specify strength = 0-0-1-0
.inputContainer .icon {....} // specify strength = 0-0-2-0`
`.inputContainer .icon` have a higher number, is stronger so this rule will override the same styles in `.icon`. If in yous code you don't have other styled for `.icon` this shouldn't be the problem.